# onListItemClick is not working for listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, onitemclicklistener

Hi onListItemClick for listview is not working.  Here i am fetching datas from SQLite using AsyncTask and displaying it in a list view. And i wants to do some actions when a list in a listview has clicked. But the click is not happening. I had tried a lot for this. Please help me.
Here is my code

```
    package com.applexus.app.mobilesalesorder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import com.applexus.app.library.sql.SqlConnector;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class SoldToPartiesList extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> idk = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> inco1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> tel = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> vwerk = new ArrayList<String>();
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String prefNamesalesorgid = "salesorgid";
    private String prefNamedistchnlid = "distchnlid";
    private String prefNamedivid = "divid";
    private String prefName = "mso";
    private TextView titlename;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvlist;
        TextView tvlistsmall;
    }

    private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder;
            final int place = position;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listso, null);              
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvlist = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textViewlist);
                holder.tvlistsmall = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);          
                convertView.setTag(holder); 
//              
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.tvlist.setText(idk.get(position));
            holder.tvlistsmall.setText(data.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }


    }

    Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    SqlConnector con;
    String salorg;
    String distch;
    String division;
    Context co = this;
    Boolean searchable=false;
    TextView tvmc;
    TextView tvmn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.materiallist);
        titlename = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewtitle);
        titlename.setText(R.string.soldtoparties);
        tvmc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewmc);
        tvmn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewmn);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        salorg = (prefs.getString(prefNamesalesorgid, ""));
        distch = (prefs.getString(prefNamedistchnlid, ""));
        division=(prefs.getString(prefNamedivid, ""));
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { null });

//      ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
//      lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new )
    }

    EditText es;
    LinearLayout ls;
    LinearLayout mc;
    LinearLayout mn;
    Boolean searchFlag = false;
    String search;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        es = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
        ls = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutsearch);

    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTasksearch extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Cursor c;
        ProgressBar pb;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            con = new SqlConnector(co);
            try {
                if (searchFlag) {
                    c = con.select("select Kunnr,Name,Name1,Inco1,Vwerk,SmtpAddr,Telf1 from tb_soldtoparties where salesorg='"
                            + salorg + "' and channel='" + distch + "' and Name like '%"+search+"%' and division='"+division+"';");

                } else {
                    c = con.select("select Kunnr,Name,Name1,Inco1,Vwerk,SmtpAddr,Telf1 from tb_soldtoparties where salesorg='"
                            + salorg + "' and channel='" + distch + "' and Kunnr like '%"+search+"%' and division='"+division+"';");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int in = c.getCount();
            c.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < in; i++) {

                idk.add(c.getString(0));
                data.add(c.getString(1));
                name1.add(c.getString(2));
                inco1.add(c.getString(3));
                vwerk.add(c.getString(4));
                email.add(c.getString(5));
                tel.add(c.getString(6));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(SoldToPartiesList.this));
            pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            searchable=true;
            con.close();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            idk.clear();
            data.clear();
            name1.clear();
            inco1.clear();
            vwerk.clear();
            email.clear();
            tel.clear();
            setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(SoldToPartiesList.this));
            pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchable=false;
        }
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Cursor c;
        ProgressBar pb;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            con = new SqlConnector(co);
            try {
                c = con.select("select Kunnr,Name,Name1,Inco1,Vwerk,SmtpAddr,Telf1 from tb_soldtoparties where salesorg='"
                        + salorg + "' and channel='" + distch + "' and division='"+division+"';");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int in = c.getCount();
            c.moveToFirst();
            Log.d("size", "" + in + "");
            for (int i = 0; i < in; i++) {

                idk.add(c.getString(0));
                data.add(c.getString(1));
                name1.add(c.getString(2));
                inco1.add(c.getString(3));
                vwerk.add(c.getString(4));
                email.add(c.getString(5));
                tel.add(c.getString(6));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(SoldToPartiesList.this));
            pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            searchable=true;
            con.close();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            idk.clear();
            data.clear();
            name1.clear();
            inco1.clear();
            vwerk.clear();
            email.clear();
            tel.clear();
            pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchable=false;
        }
    }


//  class ClickOnList implements OnItemClickListener
//    {
//        @Override
//        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
//                long arg3) {
//            Log.d("ListView", "Position"+arg2);
//
//        }
//
//    }


//  public OnItemClickListener theListListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
//   
//  public void onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
//      Log.d("position",position+"");
//  } };


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        int place=position;
        Log.d("position",position+"");

    }
}
```

And Layout code is materiallist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bluebg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bar1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="1.5"
                android:text="@string/materials"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/search"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textUri" >

                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutsearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center" android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/listbg2" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutmc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/lbg1"
                android:gravity="center" >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewmc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Code"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutmn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/lbg2"
                android:gravity="center" >




                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewmn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/offwhite" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And listso3.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lbg"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewNamelist3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" 
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewKunn2list3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" 
            android:focusable="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your onListItemClick() put ure statements before the supr.onListItemClick() an dsee if it works.

Comment: Hi, i had put code before super, but not working

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add below code to your `TextView` in the XML

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

and try again.

Another simple solution: add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root viewgroup.

Comment: and why is that happening ? I mean is textview passing events down ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain textview consume the touch event, so onItemClick will have no opportunity to fired up.

Answer (score 3):

You should add `android:focusable="false"` for ListView row items to make ListView Clikable. Because the views in the row of ListView gain the focus so ListView is not focusable. So, in your case you can add `android:focusable="false"` to the TextViews of your ListView row.

Comment: Hi, I added android:focusable="false" for textviews, but now also its not working.

Comment: Trying adding as dreamtale opted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms, and it drove me crazy for a while.  Adding `android:focusable="false"` for the list items as suggested above fixed the problem for me.

But the real issue was that I had set `android:textIsSelectable="true"` for my list items (in response to a Warning generated by Eclipse); setting `android:textIsSelectable="false"` fixed the problem for me, and I did not need the `android:focusable="false"` option at all.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found avoid the

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        }
    };
```

on the `ListView`, but exploit the Adapter constructor that takes a `Context` as parameter:

```
myCustomAdapter=new MyCustomAdapter(ActivityName.this,...)
```

Passing `ActivityName.this` is possible to cast the `Context` in the adapter's class as `ActivityName` in a safe way and use its methods working like callbacks:

```
((ActivityName)context).activityMethod()
```

Given that the `getView()` method of the Adapter class has a `position` parameter, is possible to pass this value to the `activityMethod(int position)` in order to know which list item has been pressed into the Activity where the `ListView` is.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.
if you have many child-control,and its to trouble to add `android:focusable="false"` to every child-control,you can add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to its parent-control.try it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while - none of the provided solutions worked for me. In the end I found that having a call to `getListView()` in my `onViewCreated()` method did the trick, although I have no idea why. This is for a Fragment rather than an Activity; not sure if this makes any difference.

```
public class NewsListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ListView listView;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        newsListView = getListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // this now works as expected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this issue and none of the suggested solutions worked. My problem was that I did an override for `onViewCreated` but didn't call `super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);`. Hopefully this will help someone else so they don't spend hours trying to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled as I by mistake put android:inputType="textCapWords" with the textbox after removing it it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Only the line below worked for me:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

The whole list_view_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!--android:focusableInTouchMode="false"-->
    <!--android:focusable="false"-->
    <!--android:clickable="false"-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_list_view_checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_list_view_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The above is to be used in getView like:

```
convertView=LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
    .inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
```

`