# How to set the correct row id to use in onItemClick?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have onItemClick listener, and I'd like to use the `id` value. But it has the same value as `position`.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id) {
    DBh.something(id);
}
```

I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter similar to the one described here:
[onItemClickListener with custom adapter and listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265743/onitemclicklistener-with-custom-adapter-and-listview)

I also tried to use row.setId(), but its int not long.

Comment: Can you please show your full code ?

Comment: there is no id in an arrayadapter, only position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not asking *why* you're trying to do this (you probably have your reasons), so will just explain *how* to do it.  As you are already implementing a custom adapter, all you need to do is override the `getItemId` method:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    //return ID based on the position
    return ...;
}
```

Then this value will be passed into other methods that receive item IDs.  Note that if you know how to get the ID from the position, then you can just do it straight in the `onItemClickListener`, as the position is passed into it.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is it you want to achieve? In your adapter, you can override "getItemId(int position)", and make it return any Id that you want to give the item. But why use the id value, why not simply use the position?

Comment: im using timestamp as global id and i need to find timestamp value for clicked element anyway.

Comment: So why don't you add the timestamp as a field in your element?

Comment: I suggested to override getItemId, and I suggested to use "postion" in stead of "itemid". How is that not an answer?