# List view click event

Tags: android, listview, click

I am using below code for listview click . But it is not working for me

```
     public class ApparelsSubcatBrand extends ListActivity{
int position_list_v;
//ListAdapter adapter;
String urlImg, pid, pname, mrp, shipping, sellinprice = null, prodSize,
        selSize,cbValue;
    ListView listView1;
    protected SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase_obj;
    Cursor cursor;

     public static String[] title_array ;
     public static String[] description_array ;

     protected ListAdapter adapter;
     SQLiteDatabase dh;

     String[] product_name = {};

      int[] to_for_text_in_list = {R.id.title_info_txt_v};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apparels_subcat_brand); 
        AndroidContext.setContext(this);
        sqlitedatabase_obj = DataBaseHelper.getInstance().getDb();
        listView1 = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.list); 


         cursor = sqlitedatabase_obj.rawQuery("SELECT _id, Key_ProductName , Key_SellingPrice  FROM APPARELS_SUBCAT_BRAND WHERE Key_ProductName LIKE ? AND Key_SellingPrice LIKE ? ",new String[]{"%","%"});


        final SimpleCursorAdapter simple=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.appareal_listview_text ,cursor, new String[]{"Key_ProductName","Key_SellingPrice"} , new int[] {R.id.title_info_txt_v,R.id.description_info_txt_v});

        setListAdapter(simple);

    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //position_list_v = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent(ApparelsSubcatBrand.this,BuyNowOffline.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("product_id", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Key_Product_ID")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Click event is not generating. This my total code for this activity. I want that when i click on first item then it retrieve corresponding product_id from data base for that item

Comment: Where is your ListView? Could you please add more code

Comment: Can you show us the full code (where you add the onClick listener)?

Comment: Is `adapter` is of type `ListView`??

Comment: I edit my code. Thanks to all for quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is similar to the problem i faced before, but because you don't show your adapter view xml or code, i can't give you the suggestive code, but you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765120/onlistitemclick-is-not-working-for-listview/).

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: @BlueGreen Your adapter view has two textviews, so see the link in the answer, i think it can help you.

Comment: @BlueGreen oh, you can try to set different color for the title and description textview and their pareant layout to see how large they are. Or you can add also add the clickable='true' to the layout. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

// Bind onclick event handler
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

                      // Put in your code here, what you wanted trigger :)

                 if(your_condition){
                      Intent intent = new Intent(ApparelsSubcatBrand.this,BuyNowOffline.class);
                 //     Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
                      intent.putExtra("product_id", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }
              }
});
```

And you must add your activity in AndroidManifest file,

```
<activity android:name = ".BuyNowOffline"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(ApparelsSubcatBrand.this,BuyNowOffline.class);
   intent.putExtra("product_id", id);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

get the value in other activity

```
long product_id= getIntent().getLongExtra("product_id", 0);
```

Comment: I am trying to store id in cursor and want to retrieve corresponding product id

Comment: You've already got it. Look at the parameters for the method. See the "Long id" part? That's what you're looking for.

Comment: In that scenario it also represent the same item id that is store in db

Comment: dear  i edited my question for your convenience. and i am really very glad to find your response.

Comment: It should be work can you put the log inside the onListItemClick. And click on item and find in log that event is fired or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this example :

lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(ClassName.this)); 
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
 { 
      @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
      { 
      } 
 });

hope it works