# ListView onClick doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've the same problem like this: [onListItemClick is not working for listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765120/onlistitemclick-is-not-working-for-listview/9765368#9765368)

But the answer doesn't work for me. Here is my code:

MyAdapter:

```
        static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView textName;
        protected TextView textDate;
        protected TextView textTime;
        protected TextView textCity;
        protected TextView textStreet;
        protected TextView textMusic;
        protected TextView numVotes;
        protected ImageButton BtMap;
        protected RatingBar rbFavorite;
        protected RatingBar rating;
        protected ImageView imgMusic;
        protected ImageView imgPic;   
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if(rowResourceId!=R.layout.search_empty_list) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflator.inflate(rowResourceId, null);
                final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.numVotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                viewHolder.rbFavorite = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.FavoriteBar);
                viewHolder.rating = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rateBar);
                viewHolder.textDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDatum);
                viewHolder.textTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
                viewHolder.textCity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCity);
                viewHolder.textStreet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textStreet);
                viewHolder.textMusic = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMusic);

                viewHolder.imgMusic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageMusic);
                viewHolder.imgPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPic);        

                viewHolder.rbFavorite.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float nr, boolean fromUser) {
                        club element = (club) viewHolder.rbFavorite.getTag();
                        if(nr>0) {
                            element.setFavorite(1);
                        } else {
                            element.setFavorite(0);
                        }
                      }
                });
                viewHolder.rbFavorite.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            float rating = viewHolder.rbFavorite.getRating();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            if(rating>0) {
                                viewHolder.rbFavorite.setRating(0);
                                bundle.putString("action", "removeFavorite");
                            } else {
                                viewHolder.rbFavorite.setRating(1);
                                bundle.putString("action", "addFavorite");
                            }

                            String user_id="1";
                            String login="1";
                            if(Slider.user!=null){
                                 user_id = Slider.user.getId();
                                 login = "0";
                            } 

                            bundle.putString("param1", user_id);
                            bundle.putString("param2", list.get(position).getClub_id()+"");
                            bundle.putString("param3", login);
                            bundle.putString("param4", "");
                            bundle.putString("param5", "");

                            if(user_id!=null && !user_id.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !user_id.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                httposts task = new httposts();
                                task.execute(bundle);
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
                viewHolder.rbFavorite.setTag(list.get(position));

            } else {
                view = convertView;
                ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).rbFavorite.setTag(list.get(position));
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            functions func = new functions();

            String open = func.getClubOpening(list.get(position));
            if(open.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) {
                open = "Geschlossen";
            }

            holder.textName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            holder.textDate.setText("Heute");
            holder.textTime.setText(open);
            holder.textCity.setText(list.get(position).getCity());
            holder.textStreet.setText(list.get(position).getStreet());
            holder.textMusic.setText(list.get(position).getMusic());
            holder.numVotes.setText(list.get(position).getNumVotes()+" Bewertungen");
            holder.rating.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                holder.rating.setRating(list.get(position).getRatingStars());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if(list.get(position).isFavorite()) {
                holder.rbFavorite.setRating(1);
            } else {
                holder.rbFavorite.setRating(0);
            }

            if (list.get(position).getImage() != null) {
                holder.imgPic.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).getImage());
            } else {
                holder.imgPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
            }

        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView1.setText(list.get(0).getName());
        }
        return view;

    }
```

And this is my row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shadow" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/View05"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_text_color" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/View01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDatum"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/club_listrow_linecolor" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textCity"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pic1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textCity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textStreet"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/View01"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textStreet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/View01"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textDatum"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textDatum"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/club_listrow_textcolor" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rateBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/small_ratebar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDatum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_below="@+id/View05"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/club_listrow_textcolor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/club_listrow_textcolor" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/FavoriteBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textDatum"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar"
    android:numStars="1"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/small_ratebar"
    android:stepSize="1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/BtMap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/View05"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgPic"
    android:src="@drawable/map_marker_32" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgPic"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/note_32" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMusic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/View01"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgPic"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/events"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rateBar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rateBar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/club_voteNum" />
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Where is your onListItemClick() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than  implementing  `onListItemClick`

SET `convertView.OnClickListner` after setting convertView
like

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if(rowResourceId!=R.layout.search_empty_list) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflator.inflate(rowResourceId, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.numVotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            viewHolder.rbFavorite = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.FavoriteBar);
            viewHolder.rating = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rateBar);
            viewHolder.textDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDatum);
            viewHolder.textTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
            viewHolder.textCity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCity);
            viewHolder.textStreet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textStreet);
            viewHolder.textMusic = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMusic);

            viewHolder.imgMusic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageMusic);
            viewHolder.imgPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPic);        

            viewHolder.rbFavorite.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float nr, boolean fromUser) {
                    club element = (club) viewHolder.rbFavorite.getTag();
                    if(nr>0) {
                        element.setFavorite(1);
                    } else {
                        element.setFavorite(0);
                    }
                  }
            });
            viewHolder.rbFavorite.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        float rating = viewHolder.rbFavorite.getRating();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        if(rating>0) {
                            viewHolder.rbFavorite.setRating(0);
                            bundle.putString("action", "removeFavorite");
                        } else {
                            viewHolder.rbFavorite.setRating(1);
                            bundle.putString("action", "addFavorite");
                        }

                        String user_id="1";
                        String login="1";
                        if(Slider.user!=null){
                             user_id = Slider.user.getId();
                             login = "0";
                        } 

                        bundle.putString("param1", user_id);
                        bundle.putString("param2", list.get(position).getClub_id()+"");
                        bundle.putString("param3", login);
                        bundle.putString("param4", "");
                        bundle.putString("param5", "");

                        if(user_id!=null && !user_id.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !user_id.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                            httposts task = new httposts();
                            task.execute(bundle);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.rbFavorite.setTag(list.get(position));

        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).rbFavorite.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        functions func = new functions();

        String open = func.getClubOpening(list.get(position));
        if(open.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) {
            open = "Geschlossen";
        }

        holder.textName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.textDate.setText("Heute");
        holder.textTime.setText(open);
        holder.textCity.setText(list.get(position).getCity());
        holder.textStreet.setText(list.get(position).getStreet());
        holder.textMusic.setText(list.get(position).getMusic());
        holder.numVotes.setText(list.get(position).getNumVotes()+" Bewertungen");
        holder.rating.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            holder.rating.setRating(list.get(position).getRatingStars());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if(list.get(position).isFavorite()) {
            holder.rbFavorite.setRating(1);
        } else {
            holder.rbFavorite.setRating(0);
        }

        if (list.get(position).getImage() != null) {
            holder.imgPic.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).getImage());
        } else {
            holder.imgPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        }

    } else {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setText(list.get(0).getName());
    }

// DO it here
// *****************************************************************************************
 //    view.OnClickListener
//*****************************************************************************************
        return view;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! But why i have to do it like this? I tried another listView with a custom Adapter and there the normal onItemClicklistener works.

Comment: @user3384194 because you have clickable item in list