# ListView onItemClick not called

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, listitem

I have a ListView with a custom adapter and list items containing TextView(s) only. The list items have an OnItemClick method set in the onCreate callback method.

```
 templatesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "templatesListView onClick()");
            //item is selected from the cursor to get necessary data
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "ListView count: " + templatesListView.getCount());

            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "messagesCursor count: " + messagesCursor.getCount());

            if (position >= messagesCursor.getCount()) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Unable to access element " + position + ", it does not exist in the messagesCursor. Cursor count: " + messagesCursor.getCount());
            }

            messagesCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            final String selectedItemName = messagesCursor.getString(1);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SendMessageActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(selectedItemName).setMessage("Do you want to use template: "+selectedItemName+"?");

            //Use template onClick
            builder.setPositiveButton("Use", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int x) {
                    messageEditText.setText(selectedItemName);
                }
            });

            //Cancel onClick
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int x) {
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

The ListView in the activity layout file is defined as:

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/templatesListView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sendButton" />
```

The list item is defined in a separate layout file as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/name_textView" />
```

The onClick method is called correctly when I run the app on Android 4.4.4, but when I run it on Android 5.1.1 it is not called at all.

The list item layout has been also created for v21+ separately, please find the code below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/name_textView"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/foreground_material_light"
    android:theme="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless" />
```

Do you guys know what should I change to make it work on API level 21+ ? Is that a matter of the xml file only (attributes?) or should I change the implementation? Cheers!

Comment: Maybe your list doesn't has any item in it atm? I'm just taking a guess because there wasn't anything that confirmed you had your listview populated. While replying please use @ followed by my name so I can be notified.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal : the listView is populated successfully with a custom adapter. Maybe the adapter causes the problem on newer API versions?

Comment: I've been working on API 23 since last 4-5 months and your code looks just fine to me. Can you please share the code inside `onItemClick()`?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal I think the additional layout file for the list item was confusing for the application. I have another list item layout for a different ListView which works perfectly. After removing the second (v21) file everything works fine. Thank you guys, I had to push myself into a brainstorm to eventually find it by accident :)

Comment: So you are unable to see a single log message triggered by an item click?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal : I was, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this,

```
android:clickable="true"
```

from your `ListView`. It is actually blocking the clicks from getting transferred to the individual rows.

Comment: @aritraroy93 still not working. But I guess this should be the .xml problem, so I will keep digging

Comment: Great man. you put me in the right direction.
i removed android:autoLink="web" and now works in <24 Api too

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I think the additional layout file was confusing for the application. It was named exactly the same as the original one, but with (v21) added at the end of it. After removing the second file it works fine.

Comment: What were the exact names of two layout files? And what was the argument you passed in your CursorAdapter which told the adapter the name of the layout file of the child?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal list_item_pattern.xml and list_item_pattern(v21).xml . The layout has been inflated with a R.layout.list_item_pattern name. It looks obvious now:)

Comment: I don't think you should be using brackets in naming files. The new layout will work as well if you remove the brackets and update the R.layout.. accordingly.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal I am pretty sure I did not create the (v21) file myself. I guess it was created by default to preserve compatibility with newer API versions.

Comment: Well in that case, it was definitely getting confused between the two files since the brackets part wasn't even being read as part of the name. Good job on finding the solution, +1'd!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this closely related problem and the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765120/onlistitemclick-is-not-working-for-listview), I think you should make some changes to your code.

Seeing that you have the `LinearLayout` which has a `ListView` as a child view - and this `ListView` has the `LinearLayout` as a child, which in turn has `TextView` as a child? In this case, perhaps the child views of your ListView should have the onClickListener. This means setting the following attributes to your `name_textView`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/name_textView" />
```

Then keep the templatesListView as :

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/templatesListView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sendButton" />
```

And finally, change your list-item linear layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:weightSum="1">
```

Give it a try and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for such a quick response. Unfortulately, the descendant focusability attribute did not solve it. I am wondering which item should actually be clickable in this case - is it the list item or the listView? Maybe the android:clickable is declared true in the wrong place?

Comment: So you have the `LinearLayout` which has a `ListView` as a child view - and this `ListView` has the `LinearLayout` as a child, which in turn has `TextView` as a child? In this case, perhaps the child views of your ListView should have the onClickListener.

Comment: Do you suggest I could implement the list item layout as a TextView, without the LinearLayout?

Comment: First off, I have made modifications to the code - following Aritra Roy's suggestion. Let's try this first and see.

Comment: I think you are misguiding him, the `OnItemClickListener` is only supposed to be on listview and there is no need for the properties you've set in the textview.